# Conditional operator not evaluating properly

Tags: javascript, conditional-operator

***Problem***

I'm trying to assign a value to a variable using a conditional operator based on the string value of another variable.

***Code***

```
const test = fnUserPlatform.platform === ('ps4' || 'xb1' || 'pc') ? 'p2.br.m0.weekly' : 'br.defaultsolo.current';
```

When fnUserPlatform.platform equals 'ps4" test evaluates properly to p2.br.m0.weekly but when fnUserPlatform.platform is 'xb1' or 'pc' it evaluates to 'br.defaultsolo.current' which is not correct.

Does anyone know why its evaluating in this way?

Comment: Can you post your function?

Answer (score 4):

By using this expression,

```
'ps4' || 'xb1' || 'pc'
```

you get the first string because this string is a [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy) value and by using [logical OR `||`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_OR_()), this value is takes as result for this expression.

If the first value would be an empty string, then the first truthy value is taken

```
'' || 'xb1' || 'pc'
      ^^^^^
```

For a better approach to check if you have an item and some values, you could take an array and check with [`Array#includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes).

```
const
    test = ['ps4', 'xb1', 'pc'].includes(fnUserPlatform.platform)
       ? 'p2.br.m0.weekly'
       : 'br.defaultsolo.current';
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to do this:

```
const test = fnUserPlatform.platform === 'ps4' ? 'p2.br.m0.weekly' : fnUserPlatform.platform === 'xb1' ? 'p2.br.m0.weekly' : fnUserPlatform.platform === 'pc' ? 'p2.br.m0.weekly' : 'br.defaultsolo.current';
```

Comment: Without brackets it always evaluates incorrect to the falsely option.  When i added brackets it fixed the issue when fnUserPlatform.platform is ‘ps4’ but it didnt fix xb1 or pc